# Laravel belongsToMany withPivot() and distinct()

Tags: laravel, distinct

How do I group the results of a `belongsToMany()` relationship that has `withPivot()` values?

`groupBy()` produces an SQL error and `distinct()` does work if there is no `withPivot()` data.

But I need the pivot data in the results.

```
// Relationship: room to chores
    public function chores(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Chore::class,
            'maps'
        )
        ->withPivot('id', 'room_id', 'chore_id', 'person_id')
        ->groupBy('chores.id');
    }
```

SQL ERROR

```
SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'pivot.maps.room_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `SELECT` clause to specify which columns should be included in the results. This allows you to specify which columns should be included in the results, while still grouping the results by the chores.id column.

```php
public function chores()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Chore::class, 'maps')
        ->select('chores.*', 'pivot.id', 'pivot.room_id', 'pivot.chore_id', 'pivot.person_id')
        ->withPivot('id', 'room_id', 'chore_id', 'person_id')
        ->groupBy('chores.id');
}
```